# How to test read from file and path (using junit)?

Tags: java, testing, file-io, junit, path

I need to execute test coverage with the JUnit framework.

I read [JUnit - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html) but I can't bind this knowledge with my example.

I understand how I can test method read from file alone but don't know how do this completely with test some path and askUserPathAndWord. How can I make good tests for this?

```
package task;
import java.io.*;

class SearchPhrase {
    public void walk(String path, String whatFind) throws IOException {
        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();
        for (File titleName : list) {
            if (titleName.isDirectory()) {
                walk(titleName.getAbsolutePath(), whatFind);
            } else {
                if (read(titleName.getAbsolutePath()).contains(whatFind)) {
                    System.out.println("File:" + titleName.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Read file as one line
    public static String read(String fileName) {
        StringBuilder strBuider = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                    fileName)));
            String strInput;
            while ((strInput = in.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuider.append(strInput);
                strBuider.append("\n");
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return strBuider.toString();
    }

    public void askUserPathAndWord() {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String path, whatFind;
        try {
            System.out.println("Please, enter a Path and Word"
                    + "(which you want to find):");
            System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
            path = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a Word:");
            whatFind = bufferedReader.readLine();

            if (path != null && whatFind != null) {
                walk(path, whatFind);
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You did not enter anything");
            }
        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SearchPhrase example = new SearchPhrase();
            example.askUserPathAndWord();
    }
}
```

Next *questions:*

- How we can completely test integration dependencies and check path?
- Which point should have good, understandably junit test?
- Do we need use fail test in this situations?
- Which max percent program we can cover?
- Should we test private and protected methods (generally)?

Comment: Seems like an awful lot of questions, to me, which seem to boil down to "How do I unit test", which is a huge topic.  Might be of interest to view this section of the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask (There are many fine books detailing good unit testing practice in Java).

Comment: I guess better will be stady in real examples, when you have some task. This is good practise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest keeping it simple to start with. In my mind, at a fundamental level, the goal of writing unit tests is to really just to ensure that your code does what intended it to do.

I think your `read` method is a good place to start. It looks like the purpose of your `read` method is to take a file name as input and return a string containing the files contents.

So, to write a test that proves that it works, first create a file named "testFile" somewhere with some dummy text inside the file such as "my test".

Then, write a unit test like:

```
@Test
public void read() {

    String testFileName = "/path/to/test/file/testFile";
    String expected = "my test";
    SearchPhrase searchPhrase = new SearchPhrase();
    String result = searchPhrase.read(testFileName);
    assertEquals(expected, result);

}
```

That's just to get you started. Once you get the hang of it, you can make improvements such as updating the path to the test file so that it isn't hardcoded. Ideally, the test should be able to run from anywhere.

As a nice extra bonus, writing unit tests makes you think about organizing your packages, classes and methods in such a way that they are more reusable and easier to understand (in addition to other benefits as well).

For example, your `walk` method is difficult to test as it's currently written. So try and think about how to make it easier to test. Maybe it can return a List of Strings representing the search results? If you make that change and search the directory containing testFile for the string "test", you know you should get one result in the list, so test for that using something like:

```
assertNotNull(searchPhrase.walk());
assertEquals(1, searchPhrase.walk().size());
```

Since you're just starting out, I suggest not to worry about percent of program your tests cover.

When writing tests, it helps me to think about if someone else were to use my code, how would they expect it to behave? Then I try and write tests that demonstrate the intended behavior.

Hope that helps!